# How to specify a property as null or a reference?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a json document in which a part can be either null or a subobject, like this:

```
[{
    "owner":null    
},
{
    "owner":{
        "id":1
    }   
}]
```

The question is if its possible to model this in json schema draft v4 using ref?

What I would like is something like this

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "owner":{
            "type":["null", "object"],
            "$ref":"#/definitions/id"
        }
    },
    "definitions":{
        "id":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "id":{
                    "type":"number"
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What you've posted should work, if you remove the `"type":"object"` from the definition.

However, a neater, more explicit way to specify alternatives is to use `oneOf`.  You can keep your `"id"` definition untouched, and just use:

```
    "owner":{
        "oneOf": [
            {"type": "null"},
            {"$ref":"#/definitions/id"}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Note: The `oneOf` keyword was introduced in [OpenAPI 3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) and is not available in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0. There is no support for "null" in OpenAPI 2.0, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111459/how-to-define-a-property-that-can-be-string-or-null-in-openapi-swagger).

Comment: @Demitri true, but this question is about JSON Schema itself, not its OpenAPI flavor.

Comment: @Helen Fair point; I had tunnel vision when I was investigating an issue. Given the overlap, hopefully the comment helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

`nullable` field will be supported in OpenApi (aka Swagger) Specification [v3.0.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.0-rc0/versions/3.0.md#fixed-fields-17)

So with this new spec your definition would look like:

```
"properties":{
    "owner":{
        "nullable": true,
         ...
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using:

```
"owner": {
  "nullable": true,
  "allOf": [{ "$ref":"#/definitions/id" }]
}
```

In ReDoc you will see than pretty:
[image]

Instead of `(object) or any` using unsupported `{"type": "null"}` with `oneOf`.

---

Or even better - make a new nullable id type: `{ "$ref":"#/definitions/id-nullable" }`