# How to specify a property can be null or a reference with swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

[How to specify a property as null or a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729973/how-to-specify-a-property-as-null-or-a-reference) discusses how to specify a property as null or a reference using jsonschema.

I'm looking to do the same thing with swagger.

To recap the answer to the above, with jsonschema, one could do this:

```json
{
   "definitions": {
      "Foo": {
         # some complex object
      }
   },

   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "foo": {
         "oneOf": [
            {"$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"},
            {"type": "null"}
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The key point to the answer was the use of `oneOf`.

The key points to my question:

1. I have a complex object which I want to keep DRY so I put it in a
   definitions section for reuse throughout my swagger spec: values of other properties; response objects, etc.
2. In various places in my spec a
   property may be a reference to such an object OR be null.

How do I specify this with Swagger which doesn't support `oneOf` or
`anyOf`?

Note: some swagger implementations use `x-nullable` (or some-such) to specify a property value can be null, however, `$ref` *replaces* the object with what it references, so it would appear any use of `x-nullable` is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not easy to do that. Even almost impossible. Your options :

#### Wait

There is a very long discussion about this [point](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/333), maybe one day it will be done...

#### Use vendors extensions

You can use [vendors extensions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#patterned-objects-9) like *x-oneOf* and *x-anyOf*. I have already taken this hard way: You must to upgrade all **used** 'swagger tools' to take into account these vendors extensions.

In my case, we needed 'only' to :

- Develops our own Jax-RS parser with customized annotations in order to extract swagger API file from sources
- Extends swagger-codegen to take into account these extensions to generate java code for our clients
- Develops our own swagger-ui: to facilitate this work, we added a preprocessing step to convert our swagger schema with our extensions to a valid json schema. It's easier to find a module to represent json schemas than swagger schemas in javascript. By cons we gave up the idea to test the API with the 'try it' button.

It was a year ago, maybe now ...

#### Refactor your APIs

Many projects don't need anyOf and oneOf, why not us ?

Comment: "Wait" - yes, apparently v3 is going to support oneOf, anyOf, but then we have to wait for the tooling and libraries that consume it.

Comment: "Extensions" - I'm consuming my swagger in python (w/ bravado-core) which does not have the extensions you mention...bummer.

Comment: "Refactor" - that would require dumbing down my api to fit the spec...I need the spec to fit my api!  The only other thing I could think to do for the case of returning $ref-or-null *now* is **not** return the property which in the case of clients (javascript in my case) would treat "undefined" as "null". But I loathe that idea.

Answer (score 79):

### OpenAPI 3.1

Define the property as `anyOf` of the `$ref` and `type: 'null'`.

YAML version:

```yaml
foo:
  anyOf:
    - type: 'null'   # Note the quotes around 'null'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
```

JSON version:

```json
"foo": {
    "anyOf": [
        { "type": "null" },
        { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Foo" }
    ]
}
```

Why use `anyOf` and not `oneOf`? `oneOf` will fail validation if the referenced schema itself allows nulls, whereas `anyOf` will work.

### OpenAPI 3.0

YAML version:

```yaml
foo:
  nullable: true
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
```

JSON version:

```json
"foo": {
    "nullable": true,
    "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Foo" }
    ]
}
```

In OAS 3.0, wrapping `$ref` into `allOf` is needed to combine the `$ref` with other keywords - because `$ref` overwrites any sibling keywords. This is further discussed in the OpenAPI Specification repository: [Reference objects don't combine well with “nullable”](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1368)

Comment: I'm using swashbuckle  5x on .net core and I want to add `"nullable": true` to `"payload": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
          }`, so it's `"payload": {
"nullable": true,
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
          }`,

Does anyone know of a swashbuckle option to do this?

Comment: @AdamDiament please [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=swashbuckle)

Comment: Thanks Helen, I've done that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424769/using-swashbuckle-5-x-specify-nullable-true-on-a-generic-t-parameter-reference)

Comment: This kind of expression has quite bad support with the libraries I use (python connexion/flask/OpenAPI 3.0). Referenced class code is generated twice, and when I submit invalid data in the referenced object, error message is messed up. This is disappointing

Comment: > Why use anyOf and not oneOf? oneOf will fail validation if the referenced schema itself allows nulls, whereas anyOf will work.

If null is part of the referenced schema, then does this even make sense to do?

Comment: @BenLongo if you know for sure that the referenced schema covers nulls, just `$ref` it directly. The `anyOf` approach is more like a fallback in case of complex composition/imheritance scenarios (i.e. if you don't know if the "parent" schemas are nullable) and to account for possible future schema updates (e.g. if the referenced schema is not nullable now, but becomes nullable after 6 months).

Comment: In my use case I went for oneOf with null because I'd consider it problematic to have a $ref to a type that also has null.

Answer (score 8):

For *OpenAPI 3.0* for some reason using `nullable: true` followed by `allOf` didn't work for the OpenAPI interpreter I'm using. As a workaround I ended up defining a *must-be-null* ref called `null_type` that I can use in an `anyOf` construct.

Like so:

```yaml
allOf:
  - anyOf:
      - $ref: "#/components/schemas/null_type"
      - $ref: "#/components/schemas/your_ref"
  - description: "optionally add other properties here..."
```

where:

```yaml
schemas:
  null_type:
    title: "OpenAPI 3.0 null-type ref"
    description: "for adding nullability to a ref"
    enum: [null]

  your_ref:
    ...
```

Comment: This is the only solution that made all the tools I'm using happy.

Comment: Confirmed for me as well (using in Postman OpenAPI 3.0.0 API definition)

Comment: If you're using YAML for the specification the enum should be a YAML array (not a JSON array):

```yml
schemas:
  null_type:
    title: "OpenAPI 3.0 null-type ref"
    description: "for adding nullability to a ref"
    enum:
    - null
```

Comment: @AxelGeNuS JSON is a subset of YAML, what's wrong with JSON arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using Swashbuckle in a .net6 webAPI. I had a property that was an object but could also be nullable. It was failing to deserialize it  when the object was null.

e.g. this worked and deserialized

```
{
  "Foo":"bar"
  "Details" {
    "Test":"value",
    "Test2":"value"
  }
}
```

But this failed to deserialize

```
{
  "Foo":"bar"
  "Details": null
}
```

In order to fix the issue I added the following to my swagger setup.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
     options.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
});
```

Which generated the following

```
"someObject": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SomeObject"
    }
  ],
  "nullable": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with OpenAPI 3.0, and the previously suggested solution didn't work for me:

```
foo:
  nullable: true
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
```

I discovered an alternative solution using `oneOf` to specify a nullable object without creating a separate nullable reference:

```
foo:
  oneOf:
  - type: object
    nullable: true
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
```