# How to define a property that can be string or null in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have JSON schema file where one of the properties is defined as either `string` or `null`:

```
"type":["string", "null"]
```

When converted to YAML (for use with OpenAPI/Swagger), it becomes:

```yaml
type:
  - 'null'
  - string
```

but the Swagger Editor shows an error:

> Schema "type" key must be a string

What is the correct way to define a nullable property in OpenAPI?

Comment: Related: [How to specify a property can be null or a reference with Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40920441/113116).

Answer (score 309, accepted):

This depends on the OpenAPI version.

#### OpenAPI 3.1

Your example is valid in OpenAPI 3.1, which is fully compatible with JSON Schema 2020-12.

```yaml
type:
  - 'null'   # Note the quotes around 'null'
  - string

# same as
type: ['null', string]
```

The above is equivalent to:

```yaml
oneOf:
  - type: 'null'   # Note the quotes around 'null'
  - type: string
```

The `nullable` keyword used in OAS 3.0.x (see below) does not exist in OAS 3.1, it was removed in favor of the `'null'` type.

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x

Nullable strings are defined as follows:

```yaml
type: string
nullable: true
```

This is different from JSON Schema syntax because OpenAPI versions up to 3.0.x use their own [flavor of JSON Schema](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) ("extended subset"). One of the differences is that the `type` must be a single type and cannot be a list of types. Also there's no `'null'` type; instead, the [`nullable`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#schemaNullable) keyword serves as a `type` modifier to allow `null` values.

#### OpenAPI 2.0

OAS2 does not support `'null'` as the data type, so you are out of luck. You can only use `type: string`. However, some tools support `x-nullable: true` as a vendor extension, even though nulls are not part of the OpenAPI 2.0 Specification.

Consider migrating to OpenAPI v. 3 to get proper support for nulls.

Comment: Would be nice to reference the 3.1 specification that this is stated. Reading on https://swagger.io/specification/ it explicitly says `Multiple types via an array are not supported`

Comment: Just to add for anyone coming to this later, for `3.0.3` specifically, `nullable: true` actually allows the `type: 'nullable'` value to be used. So you want to do `nullable: true` and `type: 'null'` together. https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#fixed-fields-19

Comment: @MichaelM there's no `type: 'null'` keyword in OpenAPI 3.0.x; instead you're supposed to use `nullable: true` as explained in this answer. The wording in the spec section you linked to is a bit confusing, but the intended meaning is that the value `null` is considered a valid value for a schema instance if this schema has the `nullable: true` attribute.

Comment: (cont.) `type: 'null'` and `type: [....., 'null']` are valid only is OpenAPI 3.1.

Comment: Hey @Helen thanks for pointing that out. I had to do a little bit of a deeper dive to try and understand what the schema was trying to say, because I was still finding myself confused. Based on this proposal https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/proposals/2019-10-31-Clarify-Nullable.md it would seem that adding `nullable: true` to `type: string` is equivalent to a JSON schema `"type": [ "string", "null" ]`, but OAS 3.0 doesn't allow `type: [ "string", "null" ]` explicitly. I'm glad in 3.1 they moved away from `nullable` because `3.0` is frustratingly confusing and limiting...

Comment: @m.spyratos I could not find your quote by the link. Instead, the spec says that the schema object "is a superset of the JSON Schema Specification Draft 2020-12", which, if you follow the next link, brings you to a page with examples exactly like in this answer (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-00).