# Additional properties not allowed: nullable swagger

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am using swagger 2.0 with node.js express 4.12.3 and mysql db.

I have created following schema -

```
  Country:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        readOnly: true
        description: "Country Id"
      country:
        type: "string"
        description: "Country name"
      created_at:
        type: "string"
        readOnly: true
        format: "date-time"
        description: "Country record creation date"
      deleted_at:
        type: "string"
        format: "date-time"
        description: "Country record delete date"
    required:
      - country
```

Here deleted_at field will be null and will not be present in db until the record is deleted.
My express based nodejs server returns the date as following -

[{"id":4,"country":"g","created_at":"2018-01-29T04:51:46.000Z","deleted_at":null},{"id":5,"country":"gaaaf","created_at":"2018-01-29T04:54:59.000Z","deleted_at":null},{"id":6,"country":"abcd","created_at":"2018-01-29T04:57:02.000Z","deleted_at":null}]

When I try to make rest call via swagger-ui I get following error-

```
"message":"Response validation failed: failed schema

validation","code":"SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED","failedValidation":true,
{"errors":[{"code":"INVALID_TYPE","message":"Expected type string but found type null","path":["5","deleted_at"],"description":"Country record delete date"},
```

After reading the docs I did following-

```
  deleted_at:
    type: "string"
    format: "date-time"
    nullable: true
    description: "Country record delete date"
```

Then I started getting this validation error in swagger-ui

**message:  "Additional properties not allowed: nullable"**

I tried setting type to object from string but even that did not worked.

```
 deleted_at:
        type: "object"
        format: "date-time"
        nullable: true
        description: "Country record delete date"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 [does not allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114322/113116) [nullable values](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/issues/399) for any types. `nullable: true` was introduced in OpenAPI 3.0, it's not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0.

The workaround is to not send `deleted_at` if it's supposed to be `null`.

Comment: I think OpenApi 3.0 is not fully supported by swagger tools. right?

Comment: Some tools support it, some do not. If you mean [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/), then it does not support 3.0 yet. There's an existing feature request https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/issues/514.

Comment: For the time being I am thinking about not sending deleted_at if it is null.