# Can properties and additionalProperties take on null value in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: jsonschema, swagger-2.0, openapi

```
"DogRequest"{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "height": {
      "type": "string"
     }
  }
}


"DogResponse"{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "bark": {
      "type": "string"
     }
  }
}
```

Note that I don't have any required properties defined.

I noticed that when making a request, I can have height=None

However, in my response, if bark=None, swagger throws a validation error, that None is not of type "string".

What is the rule for having properties (and additionalProperties) being null, EVEN if they aren't defined as required?

I did notice that for properties defined as required, it must be the case that they exist AND are not null. And if I want to allow the property to be null, I must include "x-nullable": true.

Do I have to include "x-nullable": true for properties that are not required as well?

Why am I seeing an inconsistency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a property that can be string or null in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111459/how-to-define-a-property-that-can-be-string-or-null-in-openapi-swagger)

Comment: Also related: [Additional properties not allowed: nullable Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48504816/113116)

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI 2.0 does not support `null` as the data type. Some tools use `x-nullable: true` to handle nulls, but it's not part of the OpenAPI Specification, so whether or not it will work depends on the tools you use.

Support for `null` was added in OpenAPI 3.0, where properties can be marked as `nullable: true`.

Comment: Ah I see. Using Swagger 2.0 so x-nullable: true works. 

However, do you know why I am maybe seeing that null is ok when sending a request, but not ok when receiving a response? 

For some reason, sending bark=None in the request does not throw any validation errors, and I didn't need to add x-nullable: true...

Comment: @aabb it's hard to say without seeing your actual code, and it probably depends on the framework/library you are using (there are [lots of libraries](https://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/) and their functionality may be different). Maybe your framework/library validates the responses against the OpenAPI definition but does not validate requests. Maybe when serializing requests it does not include `None` values in requests. Or something like that.