# Swagger Editor generated python-flask null type error

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui

I created my rest-ful api endpoint documentation on Swagger hub/Swagger editor. I have python-sanic based restful api endpoints. I'm generate and run python-flask server but I received error message.

> Uncaught TypeError: Swagger 2.0 does not support null types ([object Object]).

[image]

I have investigated this problem but have not found a result for the solution.

Comment: Please post your Swagger definition so that others can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Do you happen to have `type: null` somewhere in the spec? In that case, the error message is correct - OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 [does not support nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114322/113116).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I checked my .YAML file and remove null fields, problem resolved. Thanks, my mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message in the browser console:

> Swagger 2.0 does not support null types

implies that you have `type: null` somewhere in your API definition. OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 [does not support nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114322/113116).

If you need nullable types, use OpenAPI 3.0 which supports `nullable: true`.