# Swagger-Dredd: specifying more than one type for a parameter

Tags: parameters, swagger, dredd

I am trying to implement API testing in my project and i am using Dredd. Now some of my response parameters return 'null' value and that is okay according to logic. In my yml file, how do i specify that null can be a valid value apart from the normal expected value, say, string.

`cdeOutageUpdateType: {type: string}, txtDesc: {type: string},`

In the above parameter, it is okay if cdeOutageUpdateType is empty. But my Dredd test fails because of it.

`body: At '/19/cdeOutageType' Invalid type: null (expected string)`

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to define a property that can be string or `null` in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48111459/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution for this situation.
Swagger specification can be modified with an attribute "x-nullable"

`cdeOutageUpdateType: {type: string, x-nullable: true}, txtDesc: {type: string},`

The above will ignore cdeOutageUpdateType if it is null.