# Why is multiple types shown in a bad way in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have the following open api schema:

```yaml
    WaypointEntity:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: [number, "null"]
```

But it's not shown correctly in Swagger UI:

[image]

Any idea why that is? AmI specifying the types incorrectly? I'm using Open Api 3.0

Comment: I have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114322/8849071, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.0, `type` cannot be a list of types, it must be a single type. A nullable number is defined like this:

```yaml
id:
  type: number
  nullable: true   # <----
```

More info: [How to define a property that can be string or null in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48111459/113116)