# How to declare nullable property in OpenAPI 3.0.x that's compatible with AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openapi, jsonschema

We have been using OpenAPI 3.0.x specification, which adds feature for declaring `nullable` properties.

When I import this OpenAPI into AWS API Gateway, corresponding model does not honor this nullable setting.

Is there any way how to declare `nullable` property in OpenAPI 3.0.x so AWS API gateway recognises and configures underlying model with this setting as well?

Example OpenAPI specification

```
openapi: "3.0.2"
info:
  title: Test
  description: |
    API
  version: "0.1.0"
  license:
    name: Private
    url: https://fillme.one/license
servers:
  - url: /api/v1
paths:
  /accounts:
    post:
      operationId: repa
      responses:
        200:
          description: test
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                date:
                  type: string
                  format: date-time
                  nullable: true
              required:
                - date
```

Resulting JSON schema document for generated model

```
{
  "required" : [ "date" ],
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "date" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "format" : "date-time"
    }
  }
}
```

Clearly, type should be union of `["string", null]` but AWS API Gateway ignores OpenAPI specification.

Any help?

Comment: You might want to try `"type": ["string", "null"]` in your openapi document. Otherwise, this is probably a bug that should be filed with your implementation.

Comment: This does not work. I have no means to specify type union in OpenAPI 3.0.x, because it supports `nullable` property. The JSON schema is generated by AWS API GW from OpenAPI so I would have to post-process it manually, which is undesired

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS API Gateway expects models in the JSON Schema format rather than OpenAPI Schema format. Here's the relevant note [from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis) (emphasis mine):

> API Gateway supports most of the OpenAPI 2.0 specification and the OpenAPI 3.0 specification, with the following exceptions:
>
> - ...
> - **API Gateway models are defined using [JSON schema draft 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04), instead of the JSON schema used by OpenAPI.**

This means that AWS API Gateway expects `type: [string, 'null']` instead of `type: string` + `nullable: true`.

However, `type: [string, 'null']` [is not valid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114322/113116) in OpenAPI 3.0 (it's valid in OAS 3.1 though). What you can do is pre-process your existing OpenAPI file before importing it to AWS API Gateway and change the nullable type definitions to the format/syntax that AWS expects. You can try using tools such as [`openapi-schema-to-json-schema`](https://github.com/openapi-contrib/openapi-schema-to-json-schema).

Comment: Coming in later to point out that in OAS 3.0.3 you can use `nullable: true` and it will allow you to set `type: 'null'`, which should allow `type: [string, 'null']` to work as well. https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#fixed-fields-19

Comment: @MichaelM No, `type: 'null'` is [not a valid keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111459/how-to-define-a-property-that-can-be-string-or-null-in-openapi-swagger/48114322?noredirect=1#comment136878102_48114322) in OpenAPI 3.0.x.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with the following syntax:

```
fieldName:
      title: Field name
      default: null
      oneOf:
        - type: string
        - type: "null"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).