# Swagger 2.0 generator and nullability

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm generating a client-side C# api for a swagger 2.0 document using [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation), however none of the hundreds of properties that should be nullable are being generated as that, and the end result is that you use this API to retrieve anything from the server, it just explodes when a record returns null for any given property.

As I understand it [Swagger 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114322/550073) doesn't support defining nullability (crazy..)

---

What solutions can I implement for an OpenAPI generator running against a 2.0 spec regarding nullability? Surely this is a massive problem for the decade since Swagger 2.0 has been around?

Comment: Can you upgrade to OpenAPI 3.x.x?  believe OAS generator works just as well with the newer spec

Comment: It's a third party API, we are asking them to, but it isn't likely to happen. How did people solve this in 2.0 for the past 12 years?

Comment: convert the document yourself with swagger ui free version and then use that to generate the client

Comment: the other option is to modify the current file you are using with `x-nullable: true` for those properties and then regen the client side code