# Nullable property is not presented in the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore openapi schema properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v6.0.7` in an `asp.net core` project `net5.0`.

Let say I have models like these:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  A, B
}
```

and

```
public class MyModel 
{
   public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
   public MyEnum? MyEnum2 { get; set; }
}
```

and the swagger schema is generated like this:

```
"MyEnum": {
        "enum": [
          "A",
          "B"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      },
      "MyModel": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "myEnum": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyEnum"
          },
          "myEnum2": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyEnum"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
```

As you can see, there is no difference between `MyEnum` and `MyEnum?` in the open-API JSON schema!

And seems nullable enum is not presented in the schema properly.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this?

Best

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/861),and try to use `UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas()` as **domaindrivendev** said.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As **Yiyi You** suggested, I called `UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas` in `SwaggerGenOptions` like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
       c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
});
```

and now the schema is generated like:

```
"MyEnum": {
        "enum": [
          "A",
          "B"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      },
      "MyModel": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "myEnum": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyEnum"
              }
            ]
          },
          "myEnum2": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyEnum"
              }
            ],
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
```

and there is `"nullable": true` for the type `MyEnum?`.

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/861).

Answer (score 4):

The following worked well for me:

```cs
_ = services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // Enables support for nullable object properties
    c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
    // Enable detection of non nullable reference types to set Nullable flag accordingly on schema properties
    c.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me.

```cs
/// <summary>
    /// Updates already generated schema by marking $ref enum properties in it as nullable 
    /// if the orginal class property is of type nullable enum type.
    /// NB: schema filter can modify Schemas after they're initially generated.
    /// </summary>
    public class NullableEnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            var isReferenceType =
                TypeHelper.IsReference(context.Type) &&
                !TypeHelper.IsCLR(context.Type) &&
                !TypeHelper.IsMicrosoft(context.Type);
            if(!isReferenceType) { return; }

            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var members = context.Type.GetFields(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
                .Concat(context.Type.GetProperties(bindingFlags))
                .ToArray();
            var hasNullableEnumMembers = members.Any(x => TypeHelper.IsNullableEnum(x.GetMemberType()));
            if (!hasNullableEnumMembers) { return; }

            schema.Properties.Where(x => !x.Value.Nullable).ForEach(property =>
            {
                var name = property.Key;
                var possibleNames = new string[]
                {
                    name,
                    TextCaseHelper.ToPascalCase(name),
                }; // handle different cases
                var sourceMember = possibleNames
                    .Select(n => context.Type.GetMember(n, bindingFlags).FirstOrDefault())
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                if (sourceMember == null) { return; }

                var sourceMemberType = sourceMember.GetMemberType();
                if (sourceMemberType == null || !TypeHelper.IsNullableEnum(sourceMemberType)) { return; }

                // manual nullability fixes
                if (property.Value.Reference != null)
                {
                    // option 1 - OpenAPI 3.1
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114924/5168794
                    //property.Value.AnyOf = new List<OpenApiSchema>()
                    //{
                    //    new OpenApiSchema
                    //    {
                    //        Type = "null",
                    //    },
                    //    new OpenApiSchema
                    //    {
                    //        Reference = property.Value.Reference,
                    //    },
                    //};
                    // property.Value.Reference = null;

                    // option 2 - OpenAPI 3.0
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114924/5168794
                    property.Value.Nullable = true;
                    property.Value.AllOf = new List<OpenApiSchema>()
                    {
                        new OpenApiSchema
                        {
                            Reference = property.Value.Reference,
                        },
                    };
                    property.Value.Reference = null;

                    // option 3 - OpenAPI 3.0
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737104/5168794
                    //property.Value.OneOf = new List<OpenApiSchema>()
                    //{
                    //    new OpenApiSchema
                    //    {
                    //        Type = "null",
                    //    },
                    //    new OpenApiSchema
                    //    {
                    //        Reference = property.Value.Reference,
                    //    },
                    //};
                    //property.Value.Reference = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

```cs
public static class TypeHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is CLR type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsCLR(Type type) => type.Assembly == typeof(int).Assembly;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is Microsoft type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsMicrosoft(Type type) => type.Assembly.FullName?.StartsWith("Microsoft") ?? false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is value type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsValue(Type type) => type.IsValueType;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is reference type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsReference(Type type) => !type.IsValueType && type.IsClass;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if property type is nullable reference type.
        /// NB: Reflection APIs for nullability information are available from .NET 6 Preview 7.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsNullableReferenceProperty(PropertyInfo property) => 
            new NullabilityInfoContext().Create(property).WriteState is NullabilityState.Nullable;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is enum type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsEnum(Type type) => type.IsEnum || (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)?.IsEnum ?? false);

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is nullable enum type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsNullableEnum(Type type) => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)?.IsEnum ?? false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if type is not nullable enum type.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsNotNullableEnum(Type type) => IsEnum(type) && !IsNullableEnum(type);
    }
```

Based on:

- [How to specify a property as null or a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729973/how-to-specify-a-property-as-null-or-a-reference)
- [How to specify a property can be null or a reference with swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920441/how-to-specify-a-property-can-be-null-or-a-reference-with-swagger)